# How do I move a file from one unix based server to another using bash?

Tags: bash

I have two servers.  I would like to move a file from a directory in server A to a directory in server B using bash.  Anyone have any ideas on what the best way to do this would be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `scp` ([take a look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)) or `rsync` ([again, you can find some information here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rsync.htm)) ?

Answer (score 1):

copy it

```
$ scp user@server:/location/of/file .
```

delete it

```
$ ssh user@server 'rm /location/of/file'
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard commands to "move a file" include "cp" (if the remote directory is mounted), "scp" (the secure successor to "rcp") and, of course, "ftp".  Any of these commands can be scripted with "bash".  To "move" a file, your script would "rm" the original file.

If you're doing this regularly, for many files, some of which might already exist (and not need to be re-copied), then perhaps "rsync" might be a better approach:

http://www.howtoforge.com/mirroring_with_rsync

'Hope that helps!